# What is the probability that $X$ and $Y$ are within 0.1 of each other given a uniformly distributed joint pdf.

Tags: probability, self-learning

> Two construction companies make bids of $X$ and $Y$ (in \$$100,000$'s) on a remodeling project. The joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is uniform on the space $2<x<2.5,2<y<2.3$. If $X$ and $Y$ are within 0.1 of each other, the companies will be asked to rebid; otherwise, the low bidder will be awarded the contract. What is the probability that they will be asked to rebid?

The uniform pdfs for each variable are $f_x(x) = 2$ and $f_y(y) = \frac{10}{3}$. I assume these variables are independent and thus $f(x,y)=20/3$. We are interested in when the two variables are within 0.1 of each other so $X\le 2.4$. Also we need $|X-Y| \leq 0.1$ We can write this as:

$$A = P(X \le 2.4)$$
$$P(|X-Y| \le 0.1) \mid A)$$

I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: It's just the area of a subset of a square.

Comment: How about $[2,2.4] * [0,0.1]$?

Comment: The independence of $X$ and $Y$ follows from $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$; to find $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, solve $1=\int_2^{\frac{23}{10}}\int_2^{\frac52} c\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$ for $c$.

Comment: @Math1000 : Yes, you can find the areas of rectangles by integrating, but you can find areas of rectangles by much simpler methods.

Comment: True, but it is a good technique to be familiar with when you know that a density is proportional to some function (in this case computing the integral happens to be trivial though).

Comment: I think looking at the problem from many perspectives is valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline:** Draw the rectangle $R$ on which the joint density "lives." Draw the lines $y=x+0.1$ and $y=x-0.1$.  We want the probability that $(X,Y)$ lands in the part of $R$ that lies between these two lines. Call this region $S$. The required probability is the area of $S$ divided by the area of $R$.

Comment: Perhaps I have made an error but after computing $S=\frac{3}{50},R=\frac{3}{20}$ the resulting probability of $\frac{S}{R}$ is not correct.

Comment: I have to do some cooking. Will compute the area sometime today,

Comment: Break in the cooking. The line $y=x+0.1$ meets the boundaries of our rectangle at $(2,2.1)$ and $(2.2,2.3)$, The line $y=x-0.1$ meets the boundaries at $(2.1,2)$ and $(2.4,2.3)$. It is easier to find the area of the complement of $S$, a triangle and a trapezoid. That combined area is (I think!) $\frac{11}{100}$, which makes the area of $S$ equal to $\frac{1}{25}$. Divide, we get $\frac{4}{15}$. (Needs checking!)

Comment: Interesting your answer is below and mine above the book's $\frac{11}{30}$

Comment: My answer was off. The area of the triangle is $0.02$, and the area of the trapezoid (I had it wrong) is $3/40$, total $19/200$. Subtract from $3/20$, we get area of $S$ is $11/200$. Divide by $3/20$, and we get $11/30$.

Comment: I'll give the area of the compliment a shot, I must have made an error as well.

Comment: Use (after checking, but it is easy) the intersection points of our lines $y=x\pm 0.1$ with the boundary of the rectangle. This was given in an earlier comment. Now a picture and some care will give the area of $R\setminus S$, which is a right triangle plus a trapezoid.

Answer (score 1):

Although the best way to solve the exercise is to *draw a shape* - not of the function $f(x,y)$ but of the area $|X-Y|\le 0.1$ - one equivalent way to proceed is the following: $$P(|X-Y|\le 0.1)=P(-0.1\le X-Y\le 0.1)=P(Y-0.1\le X\le Y+0.1)$$ but also $$2\le X\le 2.5$$ and therefore $$\max\{2, Y-0.1\} \le X \le \min \{2.5, Y+1\} \iff \max\{2, Y-0.1\}\le X \le Y+0.1$$ Obviously $$\max\{2, Y-0.1\}=\begin{cases}2, & Y\le 2.1\\ Y-0.1, & Y>2.1\end{cases}$$ Thus the integration limits are $$\int_{2}^{2.1}\int_{2}^{y+0.1}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy+\int_{2.1}^{2.3}\int_{y-0.1}^{y+0.1}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

---

Your thought of taking conditional probability is not correct. You do not need to stipulate that $X<2.4$. If you take the integration limits correctly this will be automatically resolved. So, do not take conditional probability.

Comment: Definitely the hard way!!  This problem can be done by people who've never heard of integrals.  See the answer posted by André Nicolas. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble translating from the maximum function to the limits of integration. Reading it off I see we want to integrate over x from 2 to "whatever y is plus 0.1" and then over y from 2 to 2.1. As the limits of integration of y are 2 to 2.1 wouldn't the upper limit for x evaluate always to 2.1 to 2.2? What I really need is a drawing.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Your comment simply repeats the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: @Chris. In the first integral $x$ would be from 2 to (yes, as you say) 2.2 at most. But in the second it would be from 2.2 to 2.4. So, we cover all the cases. But, indeed, what you need is a drawing, and I repeat not of the function $f(x,y)$ but of the domain of $f$ and the area $|X-Y|\le 0.1$.

Comment: @Stef Does that not leave out 2.5? Although I suppose this is ok as we can *never* be greater than 2.4.

Comment: @Chris. Yes this leaves out 2.5 and is certainly must do so, since as you say we can never be greater than 2.4! So, it is ok. Did you draw the shape? If I had a suitable application, I would post it myself, but I have not.

Comment: @Stef Yes, also in response to André Nicolas answer above. I haven't dealt with multiple integrals in a bit so looking at it is very helpful.

Comment: @Chris These exercises are always solved with a shape. Otherwise you are going for a mistake 99%. But sooner or later you will need to integrate in a probability course....